# Why I am getting 'Error code : 400 Reason : Invalid value' creating sequences on GA Reporting Core API in R?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to fetch the data of Google Analytics via the Reporting Core API V3 in R using the package RGoogleAnalytics.

I want to get the users that were in sequence in two different specific page paths. For that I am using Regex:

```
filters_pre = paste0('ga:dimension15==',server_ab_test,';ga:hostname==',site_type)

filters_pre_category=paste0(filters_pre,';ga:users::sequence::ga:pagePath=~(^/$);->>ga:pagePath=~(^/eyeglasses-collection)')

query.init <- Init(start.date = start_date,
                     end.date = end_date,
                     dimensions = "ga:date,ga:dimension15",
                     metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:users,ga:pageviews",
                     filters = as.character(filters_pre_category),
                     max.results = 10000,
                     sort = '-ga:date',
                     table.id = 'ga:XXXXXXXXXX')

query <- QueryBuilder(query.init) 
dt_aux <- GetReportData(query, token, split_daywise = T,delay = 5)
```

As a result I am getting

```
Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) : 
  code : 400 Reason : Invalid value 'ga:dimension15==react cart turned on;ga:hostname==www.test1.com;ga:users::sequence::ga:pagePath=~(^/$);->>ga:pagePath=~(^/eyeglasses-collection)' for filters parameter.
```

Does someone knows how to use sequences to filter the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your filter (`Invalid value [...] for filters parameter`) which contains segment conditions (`ga:users::sequence`) :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#sequences

So either move your segment condition to the segment parameter or get rid of it, but don't include segment conditions in your filters:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: Here is an [example of your sequence segment](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3AtotalEvents&dimensions=ga%3AdeviceCategory&segment=users%3A%3Asequence%3A%3Aga%3ApagePath%3D~(%5E%2F%24)%3B-%3E%3Ega%3ApagePath%3D~(%5E%2Feyeglasses-collection))